# How to call an abstract function with an abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I want define a function in an abstract class which calls a abstract (virtual) function. But when I inherit from the abstract class this function is not inherited:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f(int t) = 0;

    void f() {
        f(0);
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void f(int t) override { }

    // using A::f; // uncomment to fix the problem
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.f(0); // works
    b.f();  // error: no matching function for call to ‘B::f()’
}
```

Why doesn't this work? The workaround is to use `using A::f`, but why is `A::f()` not inherited?

Comment: `A::f` *is* inherited, but it is hidden by `B::f(int)`. Name lookup stops when the name is found. Whether arguments match or not is irrelevant at this point. Clearer example: If `B` defined a member variable named `f` rather than a member function, `A::f` would not be found, either. If you write `b.A::f()` rather than `b.f()`, your program will compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `B` does not have an `f()`, only an `f(int)`.

If `B` did not have any function named `f`, then the superclass would be searched for a matching function, with overload resolution taking place. But because the subclass, `B`, does already have a function named `f`, the superclass is not searched, and the overload resolution happens in `B`.

This is what the `using` keyword is for, to make the superclass's `f()` a part of `B`'s namespace. The answer here is, really, "that's because this is how C++ works".